# Cartesian product (complexity amelioration)

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that gives the cartesiant product of two sequences that's what i did but i thought that it can be interesting to have less complexity with I want to browsing once the first sequence s1 and n times the second using map and then append all the results:

```
`let cartesian_product a b =
    let na = length a in
    let nb = length b in
    init
    (na * nb)
    (fun j -> let i = j / nb in
      at a i, at b (j - i*nb))
`
```

---

that's what i did for the moment :

```
`let rec cartesian_product a b =
 let rec aux x b () = match b () with
  | Nil -> Nil
  | Cons(e, b) -> Cons ((x, e), aux x b)
 in
 match a () with
 | Nil -> nil
 | Cons (x, a)  -> append (aux x b) (cartesian_product a b)`
```

but i didn't use map (is there a better way for doing that)??

Comment: with an example : cartesian [0;1] [2;3] will yield [(0,2);(0,3);(1,2);(1;3)] . Is it the expected result ?

Comment: yes exactly here i am using sequences not lists but it's the same manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Your `aux` function is essentially a specific case of `map` so you can write:

```
let rec cartesian_product a b = match a () with
  | Nil -> Nil
  | Cons (x, a)  -> append (map (fun e -> (x, e)) b) (cartesian_product a b)
```

As a rule of thumb when you feel the need to write a function called `aux`, take a step back and think whether you can use `map` or `fold`. In fact, you could improve my code by using a `fold` instead of deconstructing the sequence yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of the algorithm with a structure of list :

```
let cartesian_product a b =
  let open List in
  let mk_tuple l n = map (fun x -> (n,x)) l in  
   a |> map (mk_tuple b) |> fold_left append []
```

This will give you :

```
    cartesian_product [0;1] [2;3];;
    - : (int * int) list = [(0, 2); (0, 3); (1, 2); (1, 3)]
```